# Trying to install windows 7 on a windows 8 computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, downgrade

I sent my computer off to the geek squad to be repaired, but it was a 'junk out', and thus I received a new one, although, unlike my last one, this computer has Windows 8 installed on it, which I did not want.

I have a windows 7 install disk, but it is not working when I try to install it. When I try to install it, it says that:

> Windows Setup cannot find a location to store temporary installation files. To install Windows, make sure that a partition on your boot disk has at least 686 megabytes(MB) of free space.
>   Error code: 0x80070490

Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably need to first disable Secure Boot. Go into UEFI settings, find the Secure Boot setting and disable it. You should then be able to change your boot priority to CD.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to install it from Windows 8 itself ?

If yes, you might want to directly boot the media by restarting your computer and then pressing F12 key (or any other key specified generally at bottom right of the screen or in your computer's documentation).

Comment: It won't allow me to boot anything besides my USB drive.

Comment: @jatmdm Then, boot using USB drive. You can make a bootable USB drive from Win 7 disk.

Comment: You should be able to define bootable devices under the BIOS, if not you can always put the Windows Setup program directly on a USB stick with a tool such as Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool
 that you'll find here : http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool there is also WinToFlash. If you want more help you should put the brand/model of your computer so people can check out the specs and docs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Acer Aspire V5) I've tried to install Windows 7 and Windows 10 was already installed. 
So Secure Boot option was locked on Enabled.

I did the next:

1. Press F2 to get into BIOS during laptop load
2. Go to "Boot options" in BIOS
3. Change BIOS mode from UEFI to Legacy
4. Save changes and Exit
5. Press F12 during laptop load
6. Choose USB drive from list of devices to boot