# Installation from windows 10 to windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, installation

I have installed windows 10 in my pc. But now need to install windows 7 on it. I download on USB boot but did not worked I also make a partition of 900 Gb each but in vain and it shows me the following error:

Windows setup cannot find a location to store temporary installation files. To install windows make sure that a partition on your boot disk has at least 686 megabytes(MB) of free space.

Error code: 0x80070490

Comment: You will need to delete all partitions in setup.

Comment: I try I delete all partitions but in vain . I left only one hard disk on the PC which is 1.8 TB but in vain cannot install the windows 7 on my PC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to install windows 7 on a windows 8 computer](https://superuser.com/questions/548170/trying-to-install-windows-7-on-a-windows-8-computer)

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Secure Boot in UEFI settings, as per this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/548186/87805). Then change your boot priority to USB device.

The error `0x80070490` (ERROR_NOT_FOUND) could also mean that your installation files are missing or corrupted, so please verify them.

Comment: You guys know any link that could let me download the Windows 7 on boot mode in my USB please. Thanks

Comment: Not sure, try downloading from Torrent, make sure the ISO is clean.

Comment: In fact i downloaded a new latest version of windows 7 of 32bits and it worked when i run it on boot mode via usb